# how to do "half" pooling in neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to do max pooling in my network, like this:

[image]

My network is 1D (you can think the above example is  one sentence with 6 words while every word has 3 embedding )I don't know the length of feature(not every sentence has the same length), so I can't set the pool_size in tf.layers.MaxPooling1D(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/MaxPooling1D)

I just want to pooling every half features(or half sentence), Is there any function or method to do that?

Comment: How should the "halfPolling" handle odd numbers of words? both half include, both half exclude or one include and one exclude the middle word?

Answer (score 0):

(Note: My previous answer had an error that would have result in incorrect pooling windows. This one should be fine.)

Here is one possible way written in "low level" tensorflow. You might need to wrap this in a keras layer (or just use `Lambda`) to integrate it into your model.

```
x = ...  # input, shape batch x n_words x features
x = tf.reshape(x, [batch, 2, n_words//2, features])  # need to get these dimensions, can get them from tf.shape(x) as well
x = tf.reduce_max(x, axis=2)
```

This would implement max pooling; you could also use `reduce_mean` for average pooling, for example.

This has one limitation, namely it's not going to work if `n_words` is odd. In that case, you might have to check whether it is and use `tf.pad` to add one element in the word axis to make it even.

Comment: one brilliant idea ,through has some limitation, thanks